# gVim - What is ctags, and how do I use it?

Tags: windows, gvim, ctags

I am a regular [gVim](http://www.vim.org/) user on Windows, but don't do much more than install it, set up my small `_vimrc` file, and go.

Now I am trying to both understand gVim [Omni completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion), and get it to work (I found out about it via [haXe](http://haxe.org/com/ide/vim)).

Reading `:help new-omni-completion`, I saw something about `ctags`.

But going to the [ctags site](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), their site confused me.

What does `ctags` do, why do I want it?

And the most important part: how do I install it?

The page and docs that came with the source + binary archive I downloaded are confusing about installing (and seem to focus mostly on Linux, though I'm using Windows).  Most of them talk about compiling from source, and don't say what to do with the resulting binary (which the archive I downloaded already contained, pre-compiled).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctags` is a tool which is able to create a so called `tags` files. a `tags` file is essentially an index. vim is able to parse that file and knows, where certain patterns are.

eg.: you have a file `foo.h` where a function `foo_world()` is declared. `ctags` parses `foo.h` and puts a mark into the index-file `tags` where it stores the file and linenumber to `foo_world()`. in vim you are then able to jump directly to that mark. or autocomplete structures, classes, function names etc.

ctags is able to extract such information for a wide variety of programming languages. you only need `ctags` if you are a programmer and if you find that 'jump to that position in that other file' usefull.

Comment: Helpful answer, but the question I'm having the most trouble with is the last one: "how do I install it?" :)  The Windows archive includes a bunch of source, makefiles, and a couple executables, and help documents.  But the help documents seem linux focused, and don't offer much help with gVim on Windows.  Do I have to run ctags manually on each gVim source file?

Comment: errr I mean "source file" not "gVim source file" :)  Yes, I'm trying to use it as an IDE...

Comment: you grab the binary from http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ and drop ctags.exe next to gvim.exe. done.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer on Stack Overflow (even though this is an installation issue, and I think isn't *just* programming related).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745560/installing-exhuberant-ctags-on-windows-vista-and-xp

Accepting the other answer (Akira's) because it explains the rest of the question: `What is ctags, and why do I want it?`